# How do I print a long integer that I have in a register?

Tags: memory, assembly

I have defined a long integer as follows:

> > memTotal: .long 0

Then, I am adding to it with something like this:

> > addl 12(%di), %ecx

Where I then move %ecx to memTotal. My question is, how would I go about calculating the size in MB of the memTotal. I tried something along the lines of:

> > shrl $20, %eax

But how would I then print that as in int for MB?

Am I on the right track? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `memTotal` is always 32 bits in size. No need to calculate anything.

Comment: I understand a long is 32 bits, but I am looking for the hex -> MB conversion.

Comment: So your question is actually not about defining a long, not about calculating anything, not about counting memory, but about "How do I print an integer that I have in a register?" ?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you know how to print a single ASCII character. So now you need an algorithm to extract the digits from an integer `a` - I will provide one that I think is easy to understand and easy to expand (it's not necessarily the *best*).

- calculate `b := a%10`. `b` is the last digit of your number
- set `a := a/10` (integer division)
- repeat from beginning to get second-to-last digit, etc. Stop when `a == 0`.

Once you have the value of a digit, you can add a fixed constant to get its ASCII value, which you can use to print the corresponding character.

The above enables you to print a number. Unfortunately, at this point you can only print it backwards. In order to fix that, allocate a string in which you can put the digits from right to left. Start by allocating a string that will be large enough to hold *all* long ints, then come up with a modification of the above algorithm that will keep track of how many digits there are, and allocate a string accordingly.

(And yes, `shrl $20, %eax` sounds sensible for turning bytes into what is usually called MiBs. Conventions vary, but I think the usual one is 1 MB = 10^6 bytes, and 1 MiB = 2^20 bytes.)